# Python cannot find module

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspbian

So I've updated some of my pies. That implied that one of them, on which I had some python scripts, got demoted, and a new one arose in it's place. So I've moved my scripts.

One script needs the pastebin module. I have taken to install pastebin. With pip.

Now pip, says everything is installed successfully. I beg to differ. 
Running my script I get a

```
ImportError: No module named pastebin
```

pip list says

```
Pastebin (1.1.1)
pip (7.1.2)
setuptools (19.1.1)
wheel (0.26.0)
```

now, if I write pyt and double tap the tab key I see

```
python python2 python2.7
```

and for pip

```
pip pip2 pip2.7
python --version
```

says

```
Python 2.7.9
```

So, where in Gods name is my module installed, and how can I get python to see it?

Needless to say, I've reinstalled both python and pip multiple times. This is on a fresh install of raspbian.

**EDIT 1**

So, running

```
python -c "import site; print(site.getsitepackages())"
```

I get

```
['/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages']
```

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages contains Pastebin.

The other one doesn't

Running

```
python -c "import sys; print(sys.path)"
```

I get

```
['', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-arm-linux-gnueabihf', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages']
```

**Edit2**
Running

```
help('modules')
```

I get a list of modules which doesn't contain pastebin. And I've already installed a virtualenv for my project, in which I've installed pastebin with pip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

Download pastebin from here:
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pastebin/1.1.1

python setup.py install

Comment: It was literally one of the first things I've tried. It didn't work. Until now. I have no idea what I've changed, but now it worked. Anyway, thanks for making me try again.

Answer (score 1):

Having installed/reinstalled python and pip, we first want to make sure that pip is installing to the same `site-packages` location that your python 2.7.9 is using. Running `python -c "import site; print(site.getsitepackages())"` from the command line will tell you where your copy of python is searching for modules. Check that directory to see if `pastebin` is inside.

Alternatively, we can run `python -c "import sys; print(sys.path)"` to see every directory that python searches.

**Edit**

Running `python -c "import pastebin"` in command line will check to see if the python interpreter your command window is using can import the package. If there is no error here, then you are probably using a different interpreter to run your script (when the ImportError appears). The other interpreter will need to be reconfigured to search in the same directory for modules.

Comment: Updated answer as well.

Comment: same thing "ImportError: No module named pastebin"

Comment: I am able to reproduce the error on my machine, but no solution yet. Sorry.